# Highstock - Tooltip doesn't work correctly with Range Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have problem with `Tooltip` which doesn't reflects chart's data series. It shows 0 value at point where chart shows something different.

This is how it looks:

[image: Bad Tooltip]

[image]

I've created [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cy96hd4j/1/) which shows the problem.

To **reproduce** this you need to move Range selector to point shown on above charts. But be careful, you cannot stretch it. You need to click in the middle of Range Selector, otherwise it will work. If you do this correctly Your cursor will change to two-sided arrow.

And now the question time:

**Is it bug in Highstock code or mine?**

Answer (score 1):

You can disable [datagrouping](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping.enabled) then your points will be correct.

```
 plotOptions:{
        series:{
            dataGrouping:{
                enabled:false
            }
        }
 },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cy96hd4j/2/

Comment: Should I treat it as workaround for bug with dataGrouping enabled?